Memory Data Corruption When Multi-threading Writes to mmap
I am working on a high-performance message-passing asynchronous buffer that is strictly aligned to page size. To ensure data persistence in the event of a crash or an unexpected termination (without triggering sigaction), I’m using mmap to map this buffer to a file. This way, if the process crashes or is killed, I hope to recover any unprocessed data from the mapped file when the process restarts(I don't need 100% success, just a certain probability of success).
So far, this approach has been working well on most systems, without any noticeable performance overhead. However, I’ve encountered a problem on Android NDK.
The Problem:
On Android devices, I’ve noticed that once mmap is used, sometimes the memory data gets corrupted. When I disable mmap, the data behaves as expected and does not get corrupted. My suspicion is that, although I never explicitly called msync and rely on the system to periodically sync data to the file (and potentially on exit), the Android system (or possibly other operating systems) may occasionally perform an automatic sync operation when certain conditions are met — for example, when the system runs low on memory and performs swapping.
My Hypothesis:
I suspect that the system’s automatic sync process (e.g., in cases of memory pressure or swapping) is causing data corruption. Specifically, I think that the system might be syncing data from memory to the file and then back from the file to memory, breaking the expected synchronization between my threads. This is because the OS threads responsible for these operations do not respect the memory ordering constraints enforced by my application threads.
What I Want to Achieve:
I need a solution where, once the mmap is created at the start, the memory is only synchronized from memory to file and never from the file back to memory. Only memory-to-file synchronization, with no file-to-memory synchronization during the lifetime of the process.
So, Is there any way to prevent the OS from syncing data back to memory (like disabling MS_INVALIDATE or similar)?
Or, are there any alternatives or best practices for achieving this kind of persistent buffer in a multi-threaded environment?

How mmap really works
Your assumption about mmap does not match the actual implementation. Remember that both C (or C++) and Linux abstract away a lot of hardware details. Specifically, the pointer you get from mmap is not a pointer to physical RAM.
Instead, the pointer you get is an abstract value. During the lifetime of the process, data written there can be read back. In that sense, it's very much like malloc. Neither guarantees that the data is actually stored in RAM. In both cases, the data may be paged out to disk. Since you can still read back the data, the contract is satisfied.
Specifically, in your case, that disk storage would be the backing file which you specified in mmap. On the OS level, that's still very similar, because Linux often implements malloc on top of an anonymous mmap.
Like malloc, mmap won't magically solve your concurrency issues. Concurrent access by your threads requires synchronization. Like malloc, it does not matter if the data is paged out to disk or in physical RAM. Like malloc, the OS will not cause corruption.
About the only relevant difference here is that you need inter-process synchronization. malloc allocates memory that can only be accessed by the threads of one program.
What doesn't happen
Assuming that you follow the synchronization rules, Linux will never overwrite RAM with bytes from disk.
Linux will not automatically synchronize threads. This is your responsibility. Due to the finite number of CPU cores, Linux often is force to run not all threads at the same time, but that is not synchronization. Even if two threads physically run sequentially, synchronization is still required for reliable operation.

Thank you for your answer. Perhaps I didn’t express myself clearly. In fact, I have implemented very sophisticated inter-thread synchronization, and if I use memory allocated by malloc, there are absolutely no issues. The problem only arises when the memory is mapped using mmap. That’s why I have the above suspicion.

@Wkong: "very sophisticated" greatly increases the chance of subtle bugs. I trust the standard pthreads synchronization a whole lot more. The absence of issues in a single process does not prove correctness.

This inter-thread synchronization has been a reliable implementation, validated through years of stable production systems. That said, your answer gave me some insights: if the operating system doesn’t automatically sync data from the file back to memory, the issue might stem from the fact that the data the OS automatically syncs to the file is not guaranteed to be complete, correct, or consistent with the perspective of any specific thread. When this data is reloaded on the next startup, the lack of strict validation allows the corrupted data to pollute the runtime memory.

@Wkong: Correct. As a practical matter, the file on disk will reflect pages in memory. Different pages may have been saved at different times, even adjacent pages, and the page might not correspond to any state that has ever been visible to any thread. There's not just a lack of "strict validation"; there's a complete lack of validation in Linux.
